# class was expected (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient') in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo, native

This was working fine earlier.
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method getLastKnownPositionAsync on module ExpoLocation: Found interface com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient, but class was expected (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient'

I have added the below to my build.gradle file:

```js
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

package.json file:

```js
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "appcenter": "4.4.5",
    "appcenter-analytics": "4.4.5",
    "appcenter-crashes": "4.4.5",
    "expo": "~41.0.1",
    "expo-location": "~12.0.4",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.10.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "expo-updates": "~0.5.4",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "^5.0.1",
    "radio-buttons-react-native": "^1.0.4",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "~0.63.4",
    "react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-code-push": "^7.0.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.5.11",
    "react-native-geo-fencing": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.0-beta.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-looped-carousel": "^0.1.13",
    "react-native-maps": "0.27.1",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-razorpay": "^2.2.9",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-secure-storage": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-share": "^7.2.1",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.3.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.13.3",
    "react-native-version-check": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-native-webp-format": "^1.1.2",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.7.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.11.2",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 12):

This issue stems from google play services updating a few things in the latest version. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#october_13_2022

I was able to solve this issue by locking my google play services version to 20.0.0 in the `android/build.gradle` file. We were previously using '+'. [See image here for the change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwrb3.png).

Comment: Amazing! I was struggling with this issue and downgrading com.google.android.gms:play-services-location from 21.0.1 to 20.0.0 solved it.
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

As stated by Christian Mitchell the problem is due to the google play services latest version. And the solution is to force the version used in our project.

Adding googlePlayServicesVersion = "17.+" in the project build.gradle file might fix the issue for most of people but in my case it was not enough.

Using ./gradlew app:dependencies I notices that a module (react-native-activity-recognition) was referencing gms as follow : api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+' and therefore the latest version was still used globally

[image]

So the final solution for me was to target this module in the app build.gradle and prevent it from embedding gms as follow :

```
implementation (project(path: ':react-native-activity-recognition')) {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-location'
}
```

Comment: Fixed my issue and thought me something new. tnx

Answer (score 0):

You can follow up this link it just  api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+' error, you will get help https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/issues/802