# My Flutter android app with location based suddenly throw exception at google play service

Tags: android, flutter, location, google-play-services

I don't know what changes make it. I guess it start with flutter upgrade from 3.3.5 to 3.7.0.
I spent all day long with this problem. Downgrade not work. Project clean not work. New git checkout and build not work.

Here was an answer on react native. Some version of google play services has known issue about. But I didn't found to fix version of google play service on flutter.

[class was expected (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient') in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74085319/class-was-expected-declaration-of-com-google-android-gms-location-fusedlocatio)

```
E/AndroidRuntime(18632): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(18632): Process: com.vendict.vendict_for_nfc, PID: 18632
E/AndroidRuntime(18632): java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient, but class was expected (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient' appears in /data/app/~~gKUrnUKImAp2nfFppEkQjw==/com.vendict.vendict_for_nfc-s_CcDEKjsiyAuJc2YQz-8A==/base.apk)
E/AndroidRuntime(18632):    at com.naver.maps.map.util.FusedLocationSource$b$1.onConnected(SourceFile:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(18632):    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zak.zad(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:11)
E/AndroidRuntime(18632):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabe.zab(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:3)
E/AndroidRuntime(18632):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaaw.zaC(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:11)
E/AndroidRuntime(18632):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaaw.zag(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:4)
E/AndroidRuntime(18632):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabi.onConnected(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(18632):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zat.onConnected(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(18632):    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zah.onConnected(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(18632):    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:10)
E/AndroidRuntime(18632):    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zza.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:4)
E/AndroidRuntime(18632):    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzc.zze(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:3)
E/AndroidRuntime(18632):    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:31)
E/AndroidRuntime(18632):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(18632):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime(18632):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(18632):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
E/AndroidRuntime(18632):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18632):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/AndroidRuntime(18632):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

Comment: Did you set the google play services version to 20 as mentioned in the linked question?

Comment: Yes as link ext.googlePlayServicesVersion = '21.0.1' but not effected. How to fix google play services version in Flutter?

Comment: I have the same problem as well. I have tried everything but no luck.

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/android/plugin-setup#c-merging-libraries tell if dependency not matched between project and package, gradle resolve conflict by newest version. I added 21.0.1 in my android app build.gradle. But error message is same. I remove flutter directory and reinstall flutter now.

Comment: @ChongjuMai Try my case.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @seunghwanSon Can you give me more information on how to downgrade it?

Comment: @ChongjuMai In your project's pubspec.lock file, find package you want to downgrade and change version and "flutter pub get". That's all.

Comment: @seunghwanSon How did you ping point  which two libraries have the version conflict?

Answer (score 2):

In my case two packages were use different version of "google play services location package". One use 18.0.0 and another use 21.0.1(Which was updated recently.). https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/android/plugin-setup#c-merging-libraries tell me gradle how to resolve two packages which use same package but not same version. I downgrade package which use 21.0.1 to 18.0.0 and work fine.